# Style the last element having a specific class

Tags: html, css, select

I have a code like this.

```
<div class="slick"></div>
<div class="slick active"></div>
<div class="slick active"></div>
<div class="slick active"></div>
<div class="slick"></div>
<div class="slick"></div>
```

I want to style the last div having the class 'active'. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no (good) way to solve this problem in its current state with CSS. The best solution is to add an extra class to the last active div, or to use javascript

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401268/how-do-i-select-the-last-child-with-a-specific-class-name-in-css) for more details

Answer (score 0):

with the help of jQuery you can achieve it.

jQuery will find the last child of the parent and give you ability to change it by adding classes and styles.

go through this link https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

or use css like this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/

Comment: Sorry, It is not helpful.

Comment: if so follow this link. it will help for sure https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I want to style last div having the class 'active'. I've already tried your code.

Comment: oh! then this should solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298057/css-last-child-selector-select-last-element-of-specific-class-not-last-child-i